# Xcode 6.2 won't update to 7.0.1

Tags: xcode

I updated to Xcode 7 from the app store, but when I open Xcode the version still shows 6.2? 6.2 was my previous version. I also had to update my Mac OS from Mavericks to Yosemite in order to install Version 7 which I did.

Additionally, when I got the Apple Developer member center and click on Xcode version 7.0.1 it takes me to the app store and the app store update button states OPEN, but when I open the version states 'Version 6.2 (6C131e)' What's going on?

Comment: I would suggest just deleting Xcode (click the X mark in mission control) and reinstalling from the App Store. Something is definitely corrupted and that would probably be the easiest fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what is actually happening, but this same thing happened to me. I tried enabling the Apstore debug menu and resetting things, but ultimately nothing i tried worked. I ended up uninstalling Xcode (just put it in the trash and empty) and installing fresh fixed it for me.

I had previously had the version 7 beta alongside App store Xcode (6.3 in my case), so maybe that is part of the problem?

Comment: @ConfusedDeer yes, i've never had a problem with anything from the Appstore except Xcode, but I've had numerous problems with Xcode including generic "update failed" messages with no specifics given.

Comment: Removing and reinstalling fixed it.